# Running WScript within Laravel

Tags: php, python, laravel, iis, wsh

I'm trying to spawn a background python program from PHP. I can successfully do it locally using PHP but can't get it to work through Laravel/IIS. I think this is most likely due to a security setting but I can't figure it out and I'm not sure if its Laravel or IIS that is blocking it.

When I try to run it through Laravel, it doesn't throw any errors and $result = 0. It's just that nothing happens.

I'm using PHP 5.5 x86 NTS, IIS 7, and Laravel 5.

PHP code I'm using in both situations (locally, through Laravel/IIS):

```
<?php 
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
    $result = $WshShell->Run("python C:\Dashboard\public\python\dummy.py", 3, false);
?>
```

dummy.py simply writes a timestamp to a file.

Any ideas?